# What is wrong with following layout? It is not centering relativelayout in android in 5.1. Looks fine in design window

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-relativelayout

I have following layout file, displayed by a fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/add_printer_fragment_inner_rl"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_loading_dark"
            android:id="@+id/add_printer_fragment_iv"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/add_printer_fragment_tv"
            android:layout_below="@+id/add_printer_fragment_iv"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The design windows shows the correct rendering:

[image]

However, on actual device running Android 5.1.1, following is rendered:
[image]

I've not been able to figure out why. Can someone help me with this? I've tried many centeralization parameters (gravity, layout_gravity, many more I cannot remember). I did a workaround by using the combination of LinearLayouts to centralize but the layout looks way to messy too do such trivial task. So, I'm looking for simple solution.

Comment: what do you need a nested RelativeLAyout, an ImageView and a TextView, when you can do the same with a single TextView? Keword: **SIMPLIFY**.

Comment: @Rotwang Nested relative layout for some other arrangement I need later. It is not there just for a sake of it. Sorry.

Comment: But you can still remove the ImageView, since a TextView can contain a **compound drawable**. And I guess you don't actually need the RelativeLayout which stays on the outer part of the inner RelativeLayout. Nesting layouts degrades performances. As well as unnecessary Views.

Comment: Great suggestions! I will work with compound drawable and remove extra RL since with compound drawable one of the RL would be redundant...

Comment: With just one RL and one textview, the textview is still rendered in the top left corner... Sooo weird... No idea what's going on.

Comment: Just use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` for your TextView.

Comment: Looks like you have another view wrapping your root RelativeLayout. And it sets the bounds for your current views. You can enable showing layout bounds in the 'developer options' of your phone, you'll see a better picture of what's going on then.

Comment: you should add some background color to your parent RelativeLayout, and a different background color to the nested one, so it'll help better understand the situation. also, you should remove the layout_gravity field from the nested layout, as it has no meaning in RelativeLayouts and might cause unexpected behavior

Answer (score 2):

The design window sometimes show the results of the layout in the middle but in real (phone/table) is not... One way to solve it's with the code

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Sometimes design window show things in the middle screen but in real isn't.. An example is when you do an item layout for an adapter..

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a answer but, i have not enough reps for comments, yet:

How does the activity layout file your fragment is added to look like?

E.g does your fragment container really Match_Parent? If its wrap content in ur activity it would override the Match_Parent in the layoutfile u gave us.